# What does 'snippet' mean in code review?

Tags: terminology, atlassian-crucible

I am using Atlassian Crucible as a tool for code review workflow. It has a menu to create a `review` or `snippet`. What do we mean by `snippet` in context of code review?

Comment: When you use the menu to create a snippet, what does it do?

Comment: [Creating a Snippet Review](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CRUCIBLE/Creating+a+Snippet+Review)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the snippet definition from atlassian confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CRUCIBLE/Creating+a+Snippet+Review)

> Snippet Reviews are designed to be lightweight ad-hoc code reviews.

One can create a snippet with a piece of code. A snippet has a link. Users can view it and leave comments.